# Loop video file placed in interactive pdf

Tags: loops, pdf, video

I have an interactive pdf document that is displayed fullscreen. there's a navigation bar that users can press to jump to different pages.

What I need is some sort of looping screensaver (a collection of photos) that can be enabled by the user pressing a button.

I considered dropping in a video of a slideshow that I made in after effects, until I realised it's not that easy to loop the playback of that video!

How can I loop a video that I have placed onto a page in a pdf? I've read somewhere about swf's looping but I've tried that and there's no loop option when I place the file in acrobat?

Can someone give me some advice as I thought it would be pretty straightforward to loop a video and now it's looking far from easy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a slide show, meaning changing images at regular intervals, a few things could be done with Acrobat/Reader's on-board means.

In Full Screen, Acrobat allows to cycle through pages every whatever second. A button on those "screensaver" pages would get back to a "real" page. The question is whether that would interfere with the rest of the document.

Another approach would be having a Button field, icon only, read-only, no action, where you would show an image (preferably PDF) as an icon, and have a control loop running (using interval, timeout) loading different icons. This could be implemented with quite little JavaScript.